# F350 2002 wiring problems

Tags: electrical, ford, f-350

F350 2002 wiring problems. Electric mirrors were fixed and then problems with power windows, air conditioner and  radio arise. The windows, radio and air conditioner stop working after started and going down the road then start working again after about 20 minutes. The dealership says it's the ignition switch causing it and wants to charge us $500 to fix. Where is the ignition switch in this truck anyway?

Comment: The ignition switch is on the back of the key cylinder. I assume the key cylinder is on the steering column. If you pull the lower cover off the steering column you'll see the switch.

Comment: Thanks for response. The dealership that sold me this truck told me this is a 3 hour job and most of the cost is labor. Is this true? I know the part is a 20.00 part. They want to charge $500 to do the job.

Comment: Book time is an hour on the ignition switch. Book time on ignition switch rack/actuator assembly is 3 hours. I'm unsure what the ignition switch rack/actuator assembly is... maybe the shift interlock?